# Unity; Variable affects general Class rather then specific gameObject with Class attached, and gameObject variable stores value permanently

Tags: c#, debugging, inheritance, unity-game-engine, gameobject

When the `Player` shoots the `Zombie` with `Raycast` it is supposed to damage the `Zombie(clone)` until it is destroyed. However, the damage from the `Player` damages a general `Zombie` class on variable `currentHealth` rather than the `currentHealth` on each `Zombie GameObject`. Also, the `currentHealth` value remains even after the game has restarted from start.

[image: console debug errors]

```
public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth = 2;

    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        //subtract damage amount when Damage function is called
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;

        //Check if health has fallen below zero
        if (currentHealth <= 0) 
        {
            //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it 
            gameObject.SetActive (false);

            //Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        Debug.Log(name + currentHealth);
    }    
}
```

--

```
 public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public RaycastHit hit;
        public int gunDamage = 1;
        public Zombie zombie;
        public Camera fpsCamera;
        public int weaponRange = 50;
        private int layerMask = 1 << 9;

        void Start()
        {
            spawnPoints = playerSpawnPoint.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
           // bullet = GetComponent<GameObject>();
        }

        void LazerBeam()
        {
            Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
            Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, Vector3.forward * weaponRange, Color.green);

            if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, fpsCamera.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange, layerMask))
            {
                zombie.Damage(gunDamage); //kills zombie
                Debug.Log(name + " " + zombie);
            }
            Debug.Log(hit.collider);
        }

        void Update() 
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
            {
                LazerBeam();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently applying damage to the `Zombie` attached to the player instead of the one attached to the object that was hit. You can get a reference to that from `RaycastHit hit`.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, fpsCamera.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange, layerMask))
{
    Zombie zombieHit = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Zombie>();
    zombieHit.Damage(gunDamage); //kills zombie
    Debug.Log(name + " " + zombieHit);
}
```